# Form Search Onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery-events, onkeyup

I have a form in which the form should automatically search when I complete entering the 10th character in the text field but the below code is searching for each n every character I enter in the text field . . . I just want the result after completing the 10th character not for each n every character . . I have used `onkeyup` event and I set that value to 10 but still it is searching for each n every character... please do help me

```
<body OnKeyPress="return disableKeyPress(event)">
<section id="content" class="container_12 clearfix" data-sort=true>
    <center><table class='dynamic styled with-prev-next' data-table-tools='{'display':true}' align=center>
        <script>
        function disableEnterKey(e)
        {
            var key;      
            if(window.event)
                key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
            else
                key = e.which; //firefox      

            return (key != 13);
        }

        function showUser(str)
        {

            if (str=="")
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","resdb.php?id="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#id').keyup(function(){
                if(this.value.length ==10)
            });
        });//]]>  

        </script>



        <form id="form" method="post" name="form" >
            <tr><td><p align="center"><font size="3"><b>JNTUH - B.Tech IV Year II Semester (R07)   Advance Supplementary Results - July 2012</b></font></p></td></tr>
            <td><p align="center"><b>Last Date for RC/RV : 8th August 2012</b></p></td>
            <tr><td><p align="center"></b> <input type="text" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)"   onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" data-type="autocomplete"  data-source="extras/autocomplete1.php" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10" placeholder="Hall-Ticket Number">&emsp;</p></td></tr>
        </form>
    </center>
</table>
<center>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Results will be displayed here</b></div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: It's amazing to still see code that looks so ancient. Where's this from? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry. . I Didnt get u. . Still please can u help me or suggest me in this or with any Newer methods . . Thankyou

Comment: It's about the `center` and `b` tags it just reminds me of the old days. But as a tip the first block of code where you check for the key you can reduce to one line: `var key = e.which || e.keyCode`

Comment: Plus you seem to be using jQuery, why the convoluted AJAX request, just use `$.ajax` it's much simpler.

Comment: @elclanrs I am just learning Ajax and jquery friend so i dont know much about these, i am a beginner . . I would be very thankful if u can explain me or show me , thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea as your code is working. Do it this way. First check your textfield if it is more than 10 character or not. call fnc() onkeyup

```
function fnc()
 {
  length=document.getElementById("atext").value.length;
  if(length==10)
  {
      callyourajaxfunction()
   }


}
```

Comment: @Aryan have you put more than 10 characters?

Comment: No only ten characters coz already i have limited the text field to 10 character and i need to get the results only when 10th character is entered

Comment: function showUser(str)
{
{
  length=document.getElementById("id").value.length;
  if(length==10)
  {AJAX CODE}}} Worked.... THanks a LOt